# How to combine cdt,pdt, dltk in eclipse in linux?

Tags: linux, eclipse

1.

Okay this is probably lame question, but I haven't found good result searching the web.

**I want to combine cdt,pdt,dltk in eclipse**. I dont plan to code java though,lol.But because eclipse primarily act as java IDE at the 1st place, java capabilities is just a bonus for me.

Now,What to download?
Do you know any good guide to do this?

2.eclipse vs netbeans

a.which one is consume *less* memory?

b.which one is faster/snappier?


Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With eclipse3.5, use the **[p2 provisioning mechanism](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Update_UI_Users_Guide)** to load the relevant plugins and their dependencies.

[image: P2 Menu]

You can start by loading an ["all-in-one" config for **PDT**](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/downloads/), and then use the update sites (for eclipse3.5) for:

- [CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/downloads.php) : http://download.eclipse.org/tools/cdt/releases/galileo
- [DLTK](http://www.eclipse.org/dltk/downloads.php): http://download.eclipse.org/technology/dltk/updates

---

Regarding eclipse, it is reasonably fast, provided you are using the **right eclipse.ini**: See this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse/1409590#1409590).